# Can someone please tell me why this doesn't create an associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array, zend-form

I'm trying to add items to an associative array, this is for a Zend form (the select options) but for some reason the values are not the same as the option.

I am using

```
$thearray[$test->address1] = $test->address1;
```

which I would expect both the key and the value to be exactly the same (the value of `$test->address1`). What is happening is that the key is numbered (0,1,2,3,4 etc) but the value is correct, does anyone have any ideas why?

Here is my code

```
$tests = json_decode($result);

$testtwo = $tests->_embedded->house ;

$thearray = array();

foreach ($testtwo  as $test) {

    $i = $test->address1;
    $thearray[$test->address1] = $test->address1;

};
```

and then the form is created like this

```
   $this->add(array(
     'name' => 'address',
     'type' => 'Select',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Address',
         'value_options' => $thearray,
         'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
     ),
     'attributes' => array(
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'id' => 'propertyaddress',
     ),

 ));
```

var_dump of the array would be

```
array(365) { 
    [0]=> string(18) "1 property address" 
    [1]=> string(27) "2 another address" 
    [2]=> string(18) "3 another addresst"
    ....
```

var_dump of $test (inside the loop)

```
   object(stdClass)#271 (11) { 
        ["id"]=&gt; string(1) "1" ["address1"]=&gt; string(22) "1 property address" 
        ["address2"]=&gt; NULL 
        ["town"]=&gt; string(10) "the town" 
        ["city"]=&gt; string(10) "The city"
        ["county"]=&gt; string(10) "The county" ["postcode"]=&gt; string(8) "NN11 1NN" 
        ...
```

print_r of $result would be

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "‌​href":"http:\/\/shop.‌​dev\/house?page=1"
      },
      "‌​first":{
         "href":"http:‌​\/\/shop.dev\/house"
      }      ‌​,
      "last":{
         "href":"http‌​:\/\/shop.dev\/house?‌​page=1"
      }
   },
   "_embedded"   ‌​:{
      "house":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            ‌​"address1":"1 property address",
            "address2":‌​null,
            "town":"town",
            "c‌​ity":"city",
            "county":‌​"county",
            "postcode":"‌​NN11 1NN",
            "branch":"BRANCH NAME",
            "propertytyp‌​e":"property type",
            "landlord":"L‌​andlord name",
            "_links":{
               "sel‌​f":{
                  "href":"http:\/\/‌​shop.dev\/house\/1"
               }
            }            ‌​
         }
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the various arrays in question

Comment: Also `var_dump( $test );` would be helpful.

Comment: And the original JSONString in $result please

Comment: How do you verify the `keys`? After or before `zend` kicks in, because the code above should work

Comment: Apologies, I am new to stackoverflow. I have updated my question rather than add comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using;

```
 $c = array_combine($thearray, $thearray);
```

and then

```
 'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Address',
             'value_options' => $c,
             'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
         ),
```

I'm not sure if this is a correct solution but it has at least solved my problem.

Thank you all for your input

Clint